# Compiler improperly includes files in same directory

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

First time using stack overflow.
I am attempting to practice Object oriented abstraction and interfaces. I have been unable to get the program to compile, my program is as below.

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "Spells.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    spell MagicalSpell;
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Spells.h

```cpp
#pragma once

class spell {
private:
    int EnergyCost;
public:
    spell();
    ~spell();
    void SpellEffect();

};
```

Spell.cpp

```
#include "Spells.h"
#include <iostream>

spell::spell() {
    EnergyCost = 0;
}

spell::~spell() {

}

void spell::SpellEffect(){
    std::cout << "woosh" << std::endl;
}
```

Every time I attempt to compile main.cpp I get:

```
g++     main.cpp  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o main
/tmp/ccnXk1TN.o: In function `main': 
main.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `spell::spell()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `spell::~spell()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `spell::~spell()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

The following link seems to describe most of the issue.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/902857/error-tmp-ccob6cit-o-in-function-main-example-c-text0x4a
That person appears to be using a standard library, I think I am just attempting to use individual files that are in the same directory.

I have used multiple files together before from classwork and have not run into this problem. I can still get those files to compile and execute.
Did I make a mistake in having the files include each other? Am I supposed to use a different form of a gcc compile command?

Comment: Those are linker errors, you are compiling main.cpp without errors. What you are missing is also compiling and linking in Spell.cpp.

Comment: The title seems to have nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't passing `Spell.cpp` to `g++`.

With the options you have provided, `g++` will attempt to both compile the files listed in its arguments and to link the resulting object files together to produce a final executable. However, since `Spell.cpp` is never compiled, the linker cannot find a a definition for `spell::spell` or `spell::~spell`.

The simplest fix is to provide all translation units to `g++`, e.g.

```
g++ main.cpp Spell.cpp -o main
```